# finding gappy sublists within a certain range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pattern-matching, sublist

Recently [I asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355412/finding-gappy-sublists-within-a-larger-list) where I wanted to find sublists within a larger list. I have a similar but slightly different question. Suppose I have this list:

```
 [['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'],
 ['she', 'is', 'a', 'lawer'],
 ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student'],
 ['i', 'am', 'a', 'teacher'],
 ['she', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'very', 'exceptionally', 'good', 'student']]
```

and I want to query it using `matches = ['she', 'is', 'student']`, with the intention to bring from the queried list, all the sublists that contain the elements of`matches` in the same order. The only difference with the question in the link is that I want to add a `range` parameter to the `find_gappy` function so it would refrain from retrieving sublists in which the gap(s) between elements exceeds the specified range. For instance, in the example above, I would like a function like this:

```
matches = ['she', 'is', 'student']
x = [i for i in x if find_gappy(i, matches, range=2)]
```

which would return:

```
[['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'], ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student']]
```

The last element doesn't show up since in the sentence `she is a very very exceptionally good student`, the distance between `a` and `good` exceeds the range limit.

How can I write such a function?the gap between

Comment: Should the _gappy_ limit apply between any of the words or is it a collective _gappy_ limit - i.e. should `['she', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'is', 'a', 'zzz', 'student']` match given that the max gap between any two words is 2, but the total gap is 4.

Comment: Either extend the range limit or remove it entirely - seems obvious so I assume there is a reason you can't do this? Incidentally, I was at University with Clem's  niece!

Comment: @zwer The gap limit applies between any of the words. It is not a collective limit.

Comment: What about the order of `matches`? Is it always as same as the original matches passed to the function?

Comment: @PaulaThomas My  niece doesn't remember you, you are bs-ing. :-D

Comment: @Kasramvd The order should remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way that also takes the order of items in `match` list into the consideration:

```
In [102]: def find_gappy(all_sets, matches, gap_range=2):
     ...:     zip_m = list(zip(matches, matches[1:]))
     ...:     for lst in all_sets:
     ...:         indices = {j: i for i, j in enumerate(lst)}
     ...:         try:
     ...:             if all(0 <= indices[j]-indices[i] - 1 <= gap_range for i, j in zip_m):
     ...:                 yield lst
     ...:         except KeyError:
     ...:             pass
     ...:         
     ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [110]: lst = [['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'],
     ...:  ['student', 'she', 'is', 'a', 'lawer'],  # for order check
     ...:  ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student'],
     ...:  ['i', 'am', 'a', 'teacher'],
     ...:  ['she', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'very', 'exceptionally', 'good', 'student']] 
     ...:  

In [111]: 

In [111]: list(find_gappy(lst, ['she', 'is', 'student'], gap_range=2))
Out[111]: [['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'], ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student']]
```

If there are duplicate words in your sublists, you can use a `defaultdict()` to keep track of all indexes and use `itertools.prodcut` to compare the gap for all ordered products of word pairs.

```
In [9]: from collections import defaultdict
In [10]: from itertools import product

In [10]: def find_gappy(all_sets, matches, gap_range=2):
    ...:     zip_m = list(zip(matches, matches[1:]))
    ...:     for lst in all_sets:
    ...:         indices = defaultdict(list)
    ...:         for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    ...:             indices[j].append(i)
    ...:         try:
    ...:             if all(any(0 <= v - k - 1 <= gap_range for k, v in product(indices[j], indices[i])) for i, j in zip_m):
    ...:                 yield lst
    ...:         except KeyError:
    ...:             pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Technique in the linked question is decent enough, you just need to add gaps counting along the way and, since you don't want a global count, reset the counter whenever you encounter a match. Something like:

```
import collections

def find_gappy(source, matches, max_gap=-1):
    matches = collections.deque(matches)
    counter = max_gap  # initialize as -1 if you want to begin counting AFTER the first match
    for word in source:
        if word == matches[0]:
            counter = max_gap  # or remove this for global gap counting
            matches.popleft()
            if not matches:
                return True
        else:
            counter -= 1
            if counter == -1:
                return False
    return False

data = [['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'],
        ['she', 'is', 'a', 'lawer'],
        ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student'],
        ['i', 'am', 'a', 'teacher'],
        ['she', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'very', 'exceptionally', 'good', 'student']]

matches = ['she', 'is', 'student']
x = [i for i in data if find_gappy(i, matches, 2)]
# [['she', 'is', 'a', 'student'], ['she', 'is', 'a', 'great', 'student']]
```

As a bonus, you can use it as the original function, the gap counting is applied only if you pass a positive number as `max_gap`.